# Avoid Validating an Entity Attribute

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, save, sql-server-ce, entity

Here is one of my Entityclasses:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int CustomerNumber { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Prename { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Birthday { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "image")]
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
}
```

After adding objects, I used the following line to save my changes:

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.SaveChanges();
```

Everything worked fine, I was able to save a Customer..

Well now I must change that to the following:

```
context.SaveChanges();
```

I found out, that my previous line didn't validate, only the second does, because its inheriting from `DbContext`

Now I have the problem that I cannot save a Customer anymore, the reason is, that I got an exception at the `context.SaveChanges();` Line.

In the `EntityValidationError` I found the following Error: **ErrorMessage = "The field Image must be a string or array type with a maximum length of '4000'."**
Well know my question is, how can I avoid validating this one entity only..? I know that there is a possibilty to avoid validating *a whole* entity, but thats not the idea. I hope someone can help me, I'm stuck at this one..

Comment: an Array of bytes, the Image itselfs, no paths..

Comment: @eMi Why would you like to avoid data validation? If your DB doesn't accept the operation as the table can't store the value, what's the point?

Comment: Becuase it seems that sql-server-ce has issues to save images in the Database.. Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737733/error-storing-image-in-sql-ce-4-0-with-asp-net-mvc-3-and-entity-framework-4-1-co The problem is, I dont want to avoid validation for the whole entity, like it is described there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [CustomValidationAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.customvalidationattribute). [Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/peterblum/archive/2009/12/07/the-customvalidationattribute.aspx) is an example.

You could make a method that just returns success.

Answer (score 0):

You can also disable validation by setting the `ValidateOnSaveEnabled` configuration property on the context to `false`:

```
Context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
```